# Is there any way to recover a deleted Notes.app note that was deleted from the "Recently Deleted" folder?

Tags: data-recovery, notes.app

I created a note on my Macbook. I opened the note on my iPhone. The note was accidentally trashed on my iPhone. Once this note was deleted, it was accidentally deleted again from the "Recently Deleted" folder in Notes app. (Hey Apple, ever heard of a delete *prompt*?)

By the time I'd returned to my Macbook several hours after this incident occurred, my iPhone Notes.app had overwritten my Macbook Notes.app; the note was not found in the main folder or the "Recently Deleted" folder on the Macbook.

- The note was created after my last back-up.
- I can't shake the phone and "undo" the deletion because the "undo" feature only goes back two steps and I had already performed two actions before I knew about the "undo" feature. (Hey Apple, ever heard of an undo *button*?)
- Dr.Fone was able to recover the note's title, but not the note's contents.

Any hope to recover this file?

Comment: Ahh delete prompt the step that everyone presses OK on and complains at the waste of time that step takes

Answer (score 2):

You can recover your deleted notes as long as you have an iTunes or an iCould backup. Don't make any new backup on your iPhone because the backup files can be overwritten.

Take a look [at this tutorial](http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/blog/2014/aug/7/recover-and-retrieve-iphone-ipad-ipod-notes/). You can extract your deleted notes from an iTunes backup file on your computer. You also have a solution if you have a newer iCloud backup, as long as your phone has enough space on it and the data was not overwritten.

Comment: Great find, thanks! This worked for me! :)